# Adding a root node to Xml Document having a existing root node in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have an xml document that may look like this

```
<Stuff>
<SomeStuff></SomeStuff>
</Stuff>
```

and I want to add a new root to this document, to make it look like this

```
<Root>
<Stuff>
<SomeStuff></SomeStuff>
</Stuff>
</Root>
```

This is what i tried

```
string inputXml = " <Stuff>
    <SomeStuff></SomeStuff>
    </Stuff>";
 XmlDocument firstLossRootNode = new XmlDocument();
 firstLossRootNode.LoadXml("<Root />");
var economyDocument = = XDocument.Parse(inputXml);
firstLossRootNode.DocumentElement.AppendChild(economyDocument.Document);
```

I was trying to Append it has a child but i was getting compile time error 
Is there a way to do this in c# using Xdocument class.

Comment: Yes, there is a way. Did you try anything? When you did, what did the code look like? What did it do? How was that different from what you wanted it to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, you are using the XmlDocument class for your firstLossRootNode, but the XDocument class for your economyDocument. Is this by design? If not, the following code will do what you are trying to do:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq;

string inputXml = "<Stuff><SomeStuff></SomeStuff></Stuff>";
XDocument firstLossRootNode = XDocument.Parse("<Root />");
XDocument economyDocument = XDocument.Parse(inputXml);

firstLossRootNode.Root.Add(economyDocument.FirstNode);
```